# Android stripe - get payment methods (sources / saved cards)?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

Step 1:

```
CustomerSession.initCustomerSession
```

Step 2:

```
CustomerSession.getInstance().retrieveCurrentCustomer
```

Step 3:

I am getting the customer (test environment):

```
{ 
    "hasMore":false, 
    "id":"cus_I4xevY1VmbpCGL",
    "sources": [],
    "totalCount": 0,
    "url":"/v1/customers/cus_I4xevY1VmbpCGL/sources"
}
```

But the sources is empty, although in stripe dashboard I can see that payment method (card) is saved.

What I am trying to do is to make a custom PaymentMethodsActivity:

[image]

Comment: `customer.sources` was removed in the latest API version : https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27 (it's also deprecated in general, you should use PaymentMethods instead, like https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/stripe/com.stripe.android/-customer-session/get-payment-methods.html )

Comment: If you do want it, you should create your ephemeral key using an older API version than the latest, since it's the version you set when creating the ephemeral key on your backend that determines the API version the CustomerSession uses, I think.

Comment: customer.sources also only returns legacy card objects, which I think is probably the problem here. Really the solution is to use `customerSession.getPaymentMethods` like I mentioned, that's how to implement your use case. `sources` is legacy and you should ignore it.

Comment: you are right ... i used

Answer (score 1):

```
  CustomerSession.getInstance().getPaymentMethods(PaymentMethod.Type.Card, new CustomerSession.PaymentMethodsRetrievalListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPaymentMethodsRetrieved(@NonNull List<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods) {
            Log.d("testcustumer-size", paymentMethods.size()+" ");
            if (paymentMethods.size() > 0) {
                for (PaymentMethod method : paymentMethods) {
                    Log.d("testcustumer", method.id);
                    Log.d("testcustumer", method.card.last4);
                    Log.d("testcustumer", method.card.expiryMonth + "/" + method.card.expiryYear);
                }
                adapter = new CardsAdapter(paymentMethods);
                cardsRV.setAdapter(adapter);
                ((CardsAdapter) adapter).setOnItemClickListener((position, v) -> {
                   // paymentIntent(paymentMethods.get(position).card,paymentIntentClientSecret);
                    stripe.confirmPayment(SavedCardsActivity.this,
                            ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodId(
                                    paymentMethods.get(position).id,
                                    paymentIntentClientSecret,
                                    null
                            )
                    );
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int errorCode, @NonNull String errorMessage, @Nullable StripeError stripeError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Its throwing an error like

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to get instance of CustomerSession without initialization.
at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession$Companion.getInstance(CustomerSession.kt:498)

Can you please guide how to get all cards of user?